# SQL Server query with where statements according to a transform table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with some product data and some attributes

```
+----+------------+-------+-------+-------+
| ID |   Product  | Attr1 | Attr2 | Attr3 |
+----+------------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 | PRODUCT 1A |  150  |   11  |  763  |
|  2 | PRODUCT 1B |  250  |  411  |   77  |
|  3 | PRODUCT 2C |   42  |   99  |  903  |
|  4 | PRODUCT 3D |   70  |  165  |    0  |
+----+------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The user provides as inputs:  InputAttr1, InputAttr2, InputAttr3, Option.
I also have a mapping table between user attributes inputs and product attributes (how they should be compared)

```
+----+----------+------------+------------+------------+
| ID |  OPTION  | InputAttr1 | InputAttr2 | InputAttr3 |
+----+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | OPTION 1 |   Attr1    |   Attr2    |   Attr3    |
|  2 | OPTION 2 |   Attr2    |   Attr3    |   Attr1    |
+----+----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

According to the option input I have to compare the InputAttrs to some Product Attrs (InputAttr should be less or equal than the corresponding product attributes - according to mapping table), but I really cannot find a way to write a where statement that could handle this.

Any idea or suggestion?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the model of your mapping table as well? you can use SQL Fiddle to share the tables with dummy data.

Comment: What's the desire output based on your sample data?

Comment: PrebenHuybrechts: here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/15556/2).

gotqn: The output must be the list of products that have Attr1/2/3 greater than the ones set by the user.The mappingTable defines which InputAttr from user input must be compared to whic  Attr of the product, according to the OPTION (user input as well).
I've tried to write two examples in the query part of the SQL Fiddler, Hopefully this will make it clearer.